# How would conformal map from $\Bbb C\backslash\{z\in\Bbb C : Im(z)=0, Re(z)\le 0\}$ to the unit disc $\{|z|<1\}$ look like?

Tags: complex-analysis

How would conformal map from $\Bbb C\backslash\{z\in\Bbb C : Im(z)=0, Re(z)\le 0\}$ to the unit disc $\{|z|<1\}$ look like?

[Riemann's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem) guarantees the existence of a conformal mapping $f:\Omega\mapsto D$ where $\Omega=\Bbb C\backslash\{z\in\Bbb C : Im(z)=0, Re(z)\le 0\}$ is simply connected.

Intuitively $f$ would send points close to zero to points close to $-1$ and the half line $\{z\in\Bbb C : Im(z)=0, Re(z)\le 0\}$ would be somehow split ("with a knife parallel to the line") and wrapped around the disc's border. But since that infinitely long half line is mapped to the very finite border of the disc it would intuitively seem that $f$ is not a bijection.

Maybe it's possible to come up with an explicit $f$ and in this case I'd still like to know: how is $f$ a bijection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map $\phi(z)=\sqrt z$ transforms the given domain into the right half-plane. Now apply a bilinear (a.k.a. Möbius or linear fractional) transformation to transform it into the unit disk.